# Magento 2 cookies not working when all cache is enabled

Tags: magento-2.1, full-page-cache, cookie

In an observer I'm setting a cookie like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cookieManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');

$cookieManager->setPublicCookie('myvar', $myVar);
```

Everything is working when `Full page caching` is disabled. However, once I enable it, the cookie won't be set.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

OK. I asked the question on the official GitHub. It is quite normal if you are (like me) trying to access a cookie in a Block.

I found [this topic](http://www.techytalk.info/hole-punching-with-magento-enterprise-edition-full-page-cache/) and [especially this one](http://www.developers-paradise.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/21-Norbert-Nagy-Full-Page-Caching-in-Magento-2-for-humans.pdf) and hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to set the cookie the same way magento sets it for store by using plugins.

See file for plugin definition: vendor/magento/module-store/etc/di.xml:265

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\FrontController">
    <plugin name="storeCookieValidate" type="Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

And here you have the actual cookie set on `beforeDispatch()` vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Plugin/StoreCookie.php:69