# Magento 2 saving cookies works only on backend

Tags: magento-2.1, cookie

I have followed [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100136/how-to-add-cookie-magento-2) on how to do cookies in Magento 2, and it works, except the cookie doesn't save when I'm on frontend. However it reads well on frontend if it already exists. I have tried setting the path always to '/' since it was '/admin' on backend and '/' on frontend, but it didn't help.

```
/**
 * Name of cookie that holds private content version
 */
const COOKIE_NAME = 'auto_currency_setter_initialized_cookie';

/**
 * CookieManager
 *
 * @var CookieManagerInterface
 */
protected $cookieManager;

/**
 * @var CookieMetadataFactory
 */
protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

/**
 * @var SessionManagerInterface
 */
protected $sessionManager;

/**
 * @param CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
 * @param CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
 * @param SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
 */
public function __construct(
    CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
    SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
) {
    $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
    $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
}

/**
 * Get form key cookie
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get()
{
    return $this->cookieManager->getCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME);
}

/**
 * @param string $value
 * @param int $duration
 * @return void
 */
public function set($value, $duration = 2592000) //60*60*24*30 = 30 days
{
    //echo 'path: ' . $this->sessionManager->getCookiePath(); die;
    $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
      ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
      ->setDuration($duration)
      ->setPath('/')//$this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
      ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

    $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
        self::COOKIE_NAME,
        $value,
        $metadata
    );
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
public function delete()
{
    $this->cookieManager->deleteCookie(
        self::COOKIE_NAME,
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createCookieMetadata()
            ->setPath('/')//$this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain())
    );
}
```

I have created a logger when the the cookie is saving, and it logs just fine on both frontend and backend, but the cookie actually saves only on backend. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/215475/13553

I managed to set the cookie the same way magento sets it for store by using plugins.

See file for plugin definition: vendor/magento/module-store/etc/di.xml:265

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\FrontController">
    <plugin name="storeCookieValidate" type="Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

And here you have the actual cookie set on `beforeDispatch()` vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Plugin/StoreCookie.php:69

You could probably call your methods from your plugin.